# Publish from VS 2017 doesn't include views/web.config which throws 500 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

As the title says, I publish my MVC/.Net 4.6.2 app to my Server 2012R2 server and it throws a 500 error. If I manually copy my Views/web.config everything works again.

Am I missing an option to get it to deploy?

Comment: Is the build action for that file set to Content? Look for that in the Properties pane when you have the file selected in VS.

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks for the response. That did fix it but I wonder why it's not set that way by default if it's a required file?

Comment: My guess... VS 2017 is still a work in progress. :)

Comment: @R.Richards throw up an answer and I shall choose you! Thanks again

Comment: Answer added, glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation you all you have to do is make sure that the Build Action for the `web.config` file is set to Content. I have found that sometimes files that you need don't get set like this automatically within Visual Studio.

To make this change, find the file in the Solution Explorer. Select the file. Then in the Properties pane, set the Build Action to Content by choosing Content form the dropdown next to the property label.

Glad this helped you out.

Comment: Works for Visual Studio 2022 too